# Is there a way to get the number of intervals in a boost::icl::interval_map?

Tags: c++, boost, intervals, interval-tree, boost-icl

Is there an *built-in* way to get the number of intervals in a boost::icl::interval_map? I can't find it in the documentation. The method *size()* has a different purpose it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`interval_count` doesn't work?

In particular see the [documentation here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/function_reference/size.html).

Note that due to the way that the library is designed, these are free standing functions that take your structure as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the iterative_size() function for this purpose.